# Remove empty arrays from array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, null, empty-list

I have ajaxlistAction:

```
public function ajaxlistAction()
{   
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
   $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
   $qb->select('wfsd','b')
    ->from('TFTDataBundle:WpFormSubmittedData','wfsd')
    ->leftjoin('wfsd.customFieldData','b')
    ->leftjoin('b.custom_field','CustomField')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();


    if (!empty($_GET['sSearch'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('b.data like :search')->setParameter('search', "%{$_GET['sSearch']}%");
    }

    $qc = clone ($qb);
    $qc->select('COUNT( DISTINCT b.id)');
    $count = $qc->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    $columns = array('CustomField.fieldLabel');

    if( isset($_GET['iSortCol_0'] )){
        $dir = empty($_GET['sSortDir_0'])?'asc':$_GET['sSortDir_0'];
        $qb->orderBy($columns[$_GET['iSortCol_0']], $dir );
    }


    if (empty($_GET['iDisplayLength'])) {
        $_GET['iDisplayLength'] = 10;
    }
    if (empty($_GET['sEcho'])) {
        $_GET['sEcho'] = 1;
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['iDisplayStart'])) {
        $qb->setFirstResult($_GET['iDisplayStart']);
    }

    $qb->setMaxResults($_GET['iDisplayLength']);

    $data = array();

    foreach($qb->getQuery()->getResult() as $row ) {

        $rows = array();

        foreach ($row->getCustomFieldData() as $customFieldData) {
            $rows[] = $customFieldData->getData();

        }

        $data[] = $rows;
    }

    //$data = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    return new JsonResponse(array("sEcho"=>$_GET['sEcho'],"iTotalRecords"=>$count,"iTotalDisplayRecords"=>$count,'aaData'=>$data));
}
```

response of this action is like this

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":"44","iTotalDisplayRecords":"44","aaData":[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],["Name","email@domain.co","this is subject","this is message"],["sdsd","sas@ggkm.com","asa","sdsd"],["sdsd","sas@ggkm.com","asa","sdsd"]]}
```

And I want to remove empty arrays and want output like this

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":"44","iTotalDisplayRecords":"44","aaData":[["Name","email@domain.co","this is subject","this is message"],["sdsd","sas@ggkm.com","asa","sdsd"],["sdsd","sas@ggkm.com","asa","sdsd"]]}
```

How could I remove the empty arrays in above?

Please help me to remove these sub-arrays from the resulting array

Thanks

Comment: How did you get this array? It may be that the creation mechanism you are using provides an option to skip empty results, which would be preferable to the usual "iterate through the whole thing and skip empty sub-arrays".

Comment: Its JsonResponse and in it aaData is an array @dcsohl

Comment: you are using `leftjoin` which will return rows that are not associated with your query you will want to use `innerjoin` or `rightjoin`

Comment: Thanks @cmorrissey 
But i got another issue in output

Comment: I have total 44 records in db. As i required 4 records in 1 row that means i need only 11 rows but it show 44 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line:

```
 $data[] = $rows;
```

To this:

```
if( count($rows) > 0)
 $data[] = $rows;
```

That will check if `$rows` is not an empty array then push it into `$data` array